# XMPP Chat in Android : ChatManager not resolved

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I am trying to build a simple XMPP chat client on Android and have reached a point where I can connect and login to a public XMPP server.

I am using Eclipse and have imported the Smack Libraries using [MaventoAndroidAntPython3 script](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide#using-eclipses-android-development-tools-adt-ant-based-build). This has worked up to the connect, login stage.

I am using the following imports

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
```

strangely enough, the following imports fail, -- cannot be resolved

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
```

same problem with

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
```

while the others go through easily.

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
```

so i am able to connect, login but cannot start a chat.
what could be the problem here. how should i fix my build path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely missing the smack-im artifact. Add it to your artifacts.csv.